# C# WPF chart rotate

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

[image]I am extreamly new to C# and WPF i have managed to make a chart but i want to rotate the axis so right now my chart looks like this:

however i want it to look like this:

[image]

My XAML for the chart looks like this:

```
  <DVC:Chart Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10"   Name="MyChart" Background="LightSteelBlue" Margin="87,51,34,32" Title="Employees" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:BarSeries Title="Experiance" 
                IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" AnimationSequence="FirstToLast">
            </DVC:BarSeries>
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have tried changing flow direction to LeftToRight or not have one at all?

Comment: @N00B.NET yes i have it made it rotate 360

Comment: Anyone know how i can acheive this?

Comment: Switch your independent and dependent bindings? Your independent is x-axis and your dependent is y-axis.

Comment: @N00B.NET By doing this i get a nullpointer exepection

Answer (score 0):

Use `ColumnSeries` instead of `BarSeries`